# Java/Javascript: Is there information about font type in String?

Tags: javascript, java, string, fonts

Does Java or Javascript String contains the information about the font type? For example, font type like Arial, Comic Sans.
If yes, can I change the font type before passing in to other places like sql database?

Comment: java and javscript are completely separate and different things ... you'll need to be specific - One is essentially a toy, designed for writing small pieces of code, and traditionally used and abused by inexperienced programmers.

The other is a scripting language for web browsers. - anyway since sql database stores text, the question makes no sense, since text isn't tied to a font

Comment: A string can contain any text. So you can put the word "Arial" inside your string, if you want. But strings don't by their nature contain any formatting information about the text; just the text itself.

Comment: You might want to explain the problem you are trying to solve here. Java/Javscript Strings don't have fonts or other formatting attached, nor do the databases. They are just plain representation of text.

Comment: Please choose a language.

Comment: I am passing Strings from Web to Database.Some users will paste the text from Google Translate and submit it. Some of the font type can't show in the database, therefore would like to change the font type of the string before passing into the database. Not sure if I should do this process in Frontend Javascript or Backend Java

Answer (score 2):

Strings contain no information regarding font type.

If you are working on a web page, the font family will be declared within your CSS file.